# Не могу понять почему ошибка: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python, функции

Создал функцию, которая принимает на вход список чисел, а возвращает сумму четных чисел из этого списка.

```
def sum_num_even(*numbers):
  sum=0
  for i in numbers:
    if i%2 == 0:
      sum += i
  return sum
```

И вроде бы все работает если в функцию записываю числа через запятую:

```
sum_num_even( 1,5,6,4,3,8,9,5,6,6,6,4,3,2,1,9,9,7)
  # На выходе получается: 42
```

Однако если создаю переменную с типом *tuple or list*, и вставляю ее в качестве входных данных функции, то получаю ошибку:
**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'int'**

```
numbers = 1,5,6,4,3,8,9,5,6,6,6,4,3,2,1,9,9,7
sum_num_even(numbers)
```

Почему так происходит? Ведь по факту, если я запулливаю числа в функцию без использования переменной, то это тот же *tuple*.

```
def sum_num_even(*numbers):
  print(type(numbers))
  sum=0
  for i in numbers:
    if i%2 == 0:
      sum+=i
  return sum
sum_num_even( 1,5,6,4,3,8,9,5,6,6,6,4,3,2,1,9,9,7)
  # На выходе получается: <class tuple> и  42
```

Comment: в первом случае вы передаете не кортеж, а восемнадцать аргументов, которые распакуются в кортеж уже в функции, а во втором - один агрумент, который распакуется в `((1, 5, 6, 4, 3, 8, 9, 5, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 9, 7),)` (кортеж кортежей)

Comment: спасибо за ответ. был в шаге от того, чтобы додуматься) мог бы передать лист и увидеть, что энивей тип тупл в самой функции. 
Однако в связи с этим вопрос, можно ли как-то передать в функцию list или tuple и чтобы она работала правильно? Не используя yield

Comment: Убрать звезду перед аргументом?

Comment: Точно, спасибо за ответ. Видимо мозги уже не варят сегодня)

Answer (score 0):

С помощью *numbers мы берем значения итерируемого объекта или их присваимваем. В случае

```
def sum_num_even(*numbers):
    ...
numbers = 1,5,6,4,3,8,9,5,6,6,6,4,3,2,1,9,9,7
sum_num_even(numbers)
```

Вы распаковываете все аргументы в кортеж. Получается, что вы передали в функцию не числа, а итерируемый объект, который не получится проверить на четность.

Решение

Брать в качестве аргумента кортеж

```
`def sum_num_even(numbers): # просто берем кортеж`
```

Распаковывать кортеж перед передачей в функцию, тем самым в аргументы функции попадут только значения из кортежа

```
def sum_num_even(*numbers):
    ...
numbers = 1,5,6,4,3,8,9,5,6,6,6,4,3,2,1,9,9,7
sum_num_even(*numbers) # *numbers - мы распаковали кортеж, теперь это равносильно простой передаче аргументов sum_num_even(1,5,6,4,3,8,9,5,6,6,6,4,3,2,1,9,9,7)
```